# How to establish a distinct relationship between user and his contacts in a table

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

Please help me solve this problem

I am trying to create a relationship table in sql but the challenge I am facing is

If there are 3 users, u1, u2, u3 in user_table

```
create table user_tab
(user_id varchar2(10) not null,
 user_name varchar2(20),
 user_friend_id varchar2(10),
 constraint u_pk primary key (user_id),
 constraint fk_user_snap
 foreign key (u_s_id)
 references pic_table(user_id));

insert into user_tab values(U1,user1)
insert into user_tab values(U2,user2,U1)
insert into user_tab values(U3,user3,U1)
```

u1 adds u2, u3 in his friends list, then u2 and u3 will have a friend_id as u1

```
Select * from user_tab;

User_id User_Name User_Friend_id
U1          User1       
U2          User2       U1
U3          User3       U1
```

But if U2 adds U1 and U3 as friends, then how will the friend_id column in the row u3 hold both u1 and u2 as foreign keys? What I am trying to achieve is if U1 adds U2 as friend then the relationship can be saved by adding another column and storing U1 as friend_id, but if U2 does not add U1 as a friend then when U2 friends list is generated it should store U3,U4, so on, user_ids which U2 added

How can I address this issue? **Do I create a separate table to hold relationships**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you want to create a separate table to show relationships.

For issue 1 (Friendster)

```
create table user_tab
(user_id varchar2(10) not null,
 user_name varchar2(20),
 constraint u_pk primary key (user_id)
 );

create table friend
(user_id varchar2(10) not null,
 user_id_friend varchar2(10) not null,
 constraint u_f_pk primary key (user_id, user_id_friend),
 constraint friend_uid_fk_user_tab foreign key (user_id)
    references user_tab(user_id),
 constraint friend_uidf_fk_user_tab foreign key (user_id_friend)
    references user_tab(user_id)
);

insert into user_tab(user_id) values ('u1');
insert into user_tab(user_id) values ('u2');
insert into user_tab(user_id) values ('u3');

insert into friend(user_id, user_id_friend)
  values ('u1','u2');
insert into friend(user_id, user_id_friend)
  values('u1','u3');
insert into friend(user_id, user_id_friend)
  values('u2','u1');
insert into friend(user_id, user_id_friend)
  values('u2','u3');
```

The table friend is a relationship table between two entries in user_tab.

For issue 2 (flickr)

```
create table pic_table
(pic_id number not null,
 user_id_uploader varchar2(10) not null,
 pic_snap bfile,
 constraint snp_pk primary key (pic_id),
 constraint pic_table_uidu_fk_user_tab foreign key (user_id_uploader)
   references user_tab(user_id)
);

create table pic_rating (
  pic_id number not null,
  user_id_rater varchar2(10) not null,
  rating number,
  constraint pic_rating_pk primary key(pic_id,user_id_rater),
  constraint pic_rating_pid_fk_pic_table foreign key (pic_id)
     references pic_table(pic_id),
  constraint pic_rating_uidr_fk_user_tab foreign key (user_id_rater)
    references user_tab(user_id)  
);

insert into pic_table(pic_id, user_id_uploader) values
  (1, 'u1');

insert into pic_rating(pic_id, user_id_rater, rating) values
  (1, 'u2', 2);
insert into pic_rating(pic_id, user_id_rater, rating) values
  (1, 'u3', 3);
```

The table pic_rating is the relationship table between pic_table and user_tab.

Try working out some use case scenarios of adding, updating, and deleting relationships any you will see why this is the standard database design practice.

Comment: Jirawat, Thank you very much for helping. Regarding the first_solution, is it necessary to maintain a friend table to identify relationship between a user and his contacts? The reason I ask is if a user has 30 friends then is it necessary to have 30 rows? Is it the same principle with which facebook or twitter operates, a user has 900 contacts, then are there 900 rows? Then if his friend has 1200 contacts, then are there 1200 rows just to store the relationship information of a user? In that sense what about all the users that facebook has? does each user store a separate row to identify rel?

Comment: Yes, 1200 contacts will result in 1200 rows. If you are worried about size, since the friend table is only storing two varchar2(10), the storage will only be about 20 bytes per row (24Kb total), depending on character set. These kinds of table are called junction tables if you want to do further research.